# Best way to have a beta version system with Google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm using google appengine for business use. When I deploy something, it goes directly to production.

I would like to be able to deploy the same app to a beta version that uses the same datastore as the production site, and push to production from time to time after a complete validation.

Is there a way to do that with google appengine? What do you use?

Comment: Have you read the docs.  That's what versions are for.

Comment: Oh please, don't give me the RTFM. "There's an answer somewhere is that big doc". Stackoverflow exists because people don't know all docs all the time.

Comment: Except most people don't bother to read the docs at all, and your question is also not about programming, which is bthe focus of SO. I can't assume you have read the docs and your question lacks detail that allows people to understand your level of knowledge, or if you have even tried versions. I see a lot of people deploying new code without incrementing version numbers and I can't assume from your question that you have a clue about them.

Comment: When i post a specific question, people tell me about [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and when i post a more general question to avoid that, i get downvoted because "people can't see how far i got into this question before posting". When i search "google appengine beta"  on google, i see that THIS page is in top5 results on google. That means that the answer wasn't that easy, even if it's somewhere in the docs. If the answer isn't visible on google, the question is worth answering.

Comment: May be your should think about your terminology, I would never have thought to search for Google appengine beta, a simple query on appengine versioning will give you some good docs pertinent to your question in the first two results.  You also didn't t bother to refer to other SO questions that refer to this topic, so how do we mind read.  The down votes are a good reflection on the quality of the question.

Comment: In addition your original question specifically suggests you had no knowledge of versions which suggests you have read very little of the docs. Seriously there is no excuse for not RTFM.

Comment: I disagree. Stackoverflow is meant to build a big searchable Q/A database. If lots of people will have the same question (usually happens when the question is a simple sentence), it means that the question is worth answering, cause you also give an answer to them.

Comment: Your loss of if you can't be bothered reading docs.

Comment: your simplification (on purpose) of my argument shows your bad faith and your desire not to change your perspective.

Comment: No - you original question was severely lacking in evidence of research or attempts to resolve yourself, I was polite in not voting to close your question.  Look at my answers to other questions I go out of my way to help people with questions.  In your case you came back complaining about me suggesting you should read the docs, and I mentioned "versions" which you could then have googled for, but no you want to whine.

Comment: I did google it and i found useful stuff, therefore i'm thankful for the "version" lead. What i don't like is your way of assuming people didn't invest any effort in search before coming post here if they don't show this in the question. Asking something anywhere is longer and more tedious than searching in google or any docs for an answer. Of course i tried it first, that's basic logic. But when you have a specific question that can't be answered this way, then you have 2 options: read ALL doc (you know how long is the full appengine doc) or ask it where you can trust the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could send a small % of users to the new version as detailed here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/trafficsplitting

> App Engine's Traffic Splitting tool allows you to roll out features
>   for your app slowly over a period of time, similar to what Google does
>   when rolling out a new feature over a few days or weeks. Traffic
>   Splitting also allows you to do A/B Testing. Traffic Splitting works
>   by splitting incoming requests to different versions of your app.
>
> To set up Traffic Splitting, choose a non-default version of your app
>   with code you want to test, specify the percentage of traffic it
>   should receive, and choose the type of splitting to use. It also
>   important to pay attention to the effects of caching on the static and
>   dynamic resources in your app.

You also have options regarding routing:

> Each request arriving at an app is sent to a particular version of the
>   app. Normally, the versions are distinguished by URL. For example,
>   consider an app called codeninja with three active major versions:
>   alpha, beta, and default. All traffic sent to
>   http://codeninja.appspot.com goes to the default version, but you can
>   send traffic to other versions by including their version name as a
>   prefix (for example, you could access the beta version of the
>   codeninja app via http://beta.codeninja.appspot.com.

Comment: Nice. I guess I need to have at least one frontend for each version of my app running?

Comment: I've actually only used versions, I just happen to know this option also exists. I'd imagine that the traffic splitting tool will require a front end per version, yes.

Comment: Ok, thank you. The answer goes even a little bit beyond the scope of the question, but it's all useful information.

Answer (score 1):

You deploy with a version. Don't make it the default one and use its special url to access it. It's all explained in the appengine documents on how to deploy.

Comment: Seems a good idea, but then the DNS update to the new URL won't be transactional. You'll get old css and old js for a while, users may have problems during the DNS update...

Comment: No DNS update is required to use app versions.